# Optimizing a background image for an A0-sized poster

Tags: print-design, background, posters, canvas

I am working on a poster that will be printed on an A0-sized canvas cloth. The background image of the poster is this public domain [Indy farmland](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/94/Indy_farmland.jpg).

On top of the background, I put several panes with white background and black text.

I heard that when printing on a canvas, the background image might interfere with the texture of the canvas and look unclear. Is there a way to manipulate the image so that it looks good as a large background image?

EDIT: To see what I mean by "looks good", look at the image in a very large zoom-in. You can see stains of a reddish color inside the squares. This is not visible in the original image, but it will be visible when printing on an AO-size poster. Is there a way to clean the image of these stains?

Answer (score 1):

By default Large Format Printers print in a way that printed stuff will be scene from a long distance. like from hoarding boards. And that is normally 100+ft from an eye level. In that regards PPI (points per inch) are not that much sharp. it will be probably 85 ~ 150 or may be 200PPI. This is one thing you must keep in mind.

Some indoor printing machines do print a bit better PPI for such stuff. But canvas is after all a cloth. And cloth do have some texture that effects on Quality. Whatever sharpest PPI you produce You can't achieve very good result. so this is one more thing to keep in notice.

to have **looks good** result, you need to use those image what have either less noise image or illustration.. or other wise use artistic stuff like paintings what mostly never looses it's quality because a painting effect remains a painting effect on canvas.

You image contains a lot of noise. It's apparently looking at A0 mean a very huge size of canvas, that will have a lot of visible noise. Scaleup the image in photoshop upto 46+ inches in height. and then preview it 100%.

**Solution - to LOOKS GOOD**

- Ignore some of quality loss
- and add slight cream/offwhite color in background
- set alpha to 90 around .. slightly yellowish tone
- add sharpness and contrast
- if you see some red dots. Just lower down the red color by selective color under image adjustment in photoshop.
  This will probably be the thing you will get.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, little bit confused with "looks good". Its too general.

When i check your link, in my view, its little bit dull.

If i were you, i will use PhotoShop to manipulate the image to make "looks good" in my view.

Go to PhotoShop main menu -> Image -> Adjustments -> Levels ... (Ctrl+L)

in "Input Levels" change type

from:  `0     1.00     255`

to: `31    1.00     141`